# Python Split string with a string that is on new line

Tags: python, regex, split

I am trying to split a string with a word that is on a new line by itself.

For example, I want to split the string into parts whenever I encounter the word "SPLIT". For my use case the word "SPLIT" should only be all by itself on a new line:

I tried `str.split("\nSPLIT")`, but having trouble making it work for after the word.

```
Hello there,
SPLIT
how are you?
```

should return ["Hello there,", "how are you?"]

```
Hello there, SPLIT how are you?
```

should return ["Hello there, SPLIT how are you?"]

```
Hello there,
SPLIT
```

should return ["Hello there,", ""]

```
Hello there,
SPLIT how are you?
```

should return ["Hello there,\nSPLIT how are you?"]

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Please share the code you tried to see where the problem is.

Comment: Yeah, your question isn't totally clear. I'd like to help but I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: not sure if I understood exactly, but something like this might help: `re.match( '^(Hello there,\n)(SPLIT\n)?(how are you?)', mystring, re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I started off with str.split("\nSPLIT") and thought it's kind of easier to achieve this with `split` + regex rather than iterating over and building the substrings again.

Comment: Ok, all you need is `re.split(r'\n?^SPLIT$\n?', text, flags=re.M)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.split(r'\n?^SPLIT$\n?', text, flags=re.M)
re.split(r'(?:^|\n)SPLIT(?:$|\n)', text)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/krSAS2).

The `\n?^SPLIT$\n?` regex used with `re.M` flag matches an optional newline char, then makes sure the index is at the start of a line (`^`) and then matches and consumes `SPLIT` and then checks if there is end of a line position right after `SPLIT` and then matches an optional newline char.

The `(?:^|\n)SPLIT(?:$|\n)` regex just matches either start of string or a newline, `SPLIT` and then either end of string or a newline char. Note the use of [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) so as to avoid having newlines or extra empty strings as part of the resulting list.

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/6xU15d/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/6xU15d/2).